# Logout handler is hanging

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm upgrading a working application from Spring Boot 2.6.5 to 2.7.8 (Spring Security 5.7.6) so that I can better upgrade to 3.0.

Logout was working fine before. But after upgrading to Sprint Boot 2.7.8 the logout handling is hanging and never redirecting to the `logoutSuccessUrl()`.

Here is the complete filter chain configuration:

```java
      http
         .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
            .antMatchers("/webjars/**","/login/**","/mobile-manifest.json","/service-worker.js","/cache.manifest","/favicon.ico","/async/**","/api/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
         )
         .httpBasic(withDefaults())
         .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .successHandler(savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
            .failureUrl("/login?loginFailed=true"))
         .logout( logout -> logout
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logoutSuccess=true")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .deleteCookies(COOKIE_STRING))
         .rememberMe( rememberMe -> rememberMe
            .key(TOKEN_KEY)
            .rememberMeParameter(REMEMBER_ME_KEY)
            .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
         .userDetailsService(userSvc)
            .tokenValiditySeconds(validitySeconds));
```

The output:

```
[https-jsse-nio-7001-exec-10] [DEBUG] [o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy] - Securing POST /logout
[https-jsse-nio-7001-exec-10] [DEBUG] [o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] - Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=UserProfile [ blah blah, eventRoles=null, lastLoginDisplay=today, directoryUrl=null, groups=[]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=740230E1C02B57BEF504C23570FFA9EC], Granted Authorities=[]]]
[https-jsse-nio-7001-exec-10] [DEBUG] [o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] - Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=UserProfile [blah blah eventRoles=null, lastLoginDisplay=today, directoryUrl=null, groups=[]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=740230E1C02B57BEF504C23570FFA9EC], Granted Authorities=[]]]
[https-jsse-nio-7001-exec-10] [DEBUG] [o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter] - Logging out [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=UserProfile [blah blah, eventRoles=null, lastLoginDisplay=today, directoryUrl=null, groups=[]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=740230E1C02B57BEF504C23570FFA9EC], Granted Authorities=[]]]
[https-jsse-nio-7001-exec-10] [DEBUG] [o.s.s.w.a.r.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices] - Logout of user username
[https-jsse-nio-7001-exec-10] [DEBUG] [o.s.s.w.a.r.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices] - Cancelling cookie
[https-jsse-nio-7001-exec-10] [DEBUG] [o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] - Executing prepared SQL update
[https-jsse-nio-7001-exec-10] [DEBUG] [o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] - Executing prepared SQL statement [delete from persistent_logins where username = ?]
[https-jsse-nio-7001-exec-10] [DEBUG] [o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
[https-jsse-nio-7001-exec-10] [DEBUG] [o.s.s.w.a.l.SecurityContextLogoutHandler] - Invalidated session F3BC69312EC05C175A0FCEC298B49D06
[https-jsse-nio-7001-exec-10] [DEBUG] [o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] - Did not store empty SecurityContext
[https-jsse-nio-7001-exec-10] [DEBUG] [o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] - Did not store empty SecurityContext
[https-jsse-nio-7001-exec-10] [DEBUG] [o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

Browser is never redirected to the `loginSuccessUrl()`, all DEBUG logging ends above. CSRF is enabled and logout was submitted `POST`.

I had `.permitAll()` in the logout configuration, but it seemed to have no effect in this case.

[Screenshot showing request / response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iPwF.png)

Comment: Do you call the logout endpoint from JavaScript? This could be the reason, that you only get 204 No content response.

Comment: That was a surprising, but good guess. I added this jquery attribute: data-ajax="false" to the <form> and it does indeed redirect now.  Is this documented anywhere in spring security, or an undocumented feature? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Security provides two implementations of `LogoutSuccessHandler`, see [LogoutSuccessHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/logout.html#jc-logout-success-handler):

> **LogoutSuccessHandler**
>
> The `LogoutSuccessHandler` is called after a successful logout by the `LogoutFilter`, to handle (for example) redirection or forwarding to the appropriate destination. Note that the interface is almost the same as the `LogoutHandler` but may raise an exception.
>
> Spring Security provides the following implementations:
>
> - SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler
> - HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler
>
> As mentioned earlier, you need not specify the `SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler` directly. Instead, the fluent API provides a shortcut by setting the `logoutSuccessUrl()`. This sets up the `SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler` under the covers. The provided URL is redirected to after a logout has occurred. The default is `/login?logout`.
>
> The `HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler` can be interesting in REST API type scenarios. Instead of redirecting to a URL upon the successful logout, this `LogoutSuccessHandler` lets you provide a plain HTTP status code to be returned. If not configured, a status code 200 is returned by default.

If you configure HTTP basic authentication, the `HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler` is added, see
[Default Logout Handler with HTTP Basic and XMLHttpRequest should be 204](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3997):

> The default behavior for logout when the header X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest and HTTP Basic is enabled should be a 201. This will improve AngularJS experience which sends an accept header which includes text/html

See also: [SEC-3103: Logout Success Content Negotiation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3282).